# How to update the length of a pytorch dataset after removing some of its enteries?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am facing an error in iterating over a dataset after I have removed some of the data files from the data-path of the dataset. I understand that the length of this dataset is still the same, which is the reason for this error. I have created a dataset and saved all the corresponding files into folder_path = '/content/data/processed' .

```
datasetAB = MoleculeDataset('clintox.csv', root = '/content/data')
len(datasetAB) 
->1448
```

Later, I deleted some of the files (from unwanted_files) from this dataset using os.remove.

```
folder_path = '/content/data/processed'

files = os.listdir(folder_path)

# filter out the files with the unwanted value
unwanted_files = unwanted_files

# delete the unwanted files
for f in unwanted_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, f)
    os.remove(file_path)
```

The unwanted_files have 107 files. But still the length of this dataset is the same.

```
len(datasetAB) 
    ->1448
```

My attempt:

I tried to update the length using a method: But still it doesn't work.

```
def len(self):
    return self.data.shape[0]

def update_length(self):
    self.__len__ = len(self.data)
```

Any help on how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Magic methods are looked up on the class, not on the instance, so you cannot alter `__len__` after creating dataset.

You can either create new dataset with the new data, or modify the `object` used to calculate the length, for example `dataset.data = new_data`.

You can also define new class based on your dataset, for example:

```
training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

class new_dataset:
  def __init__(self, data): 
    self.data = data
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return self.data.__getitem__(idx)
  def __len__(self):
    return 10

ds = new_dataset(training_data)
print(len(ds))
train_dataloader = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
for img, label in train_dataloader:
  print(img.shape, label.shape)
```

However I don't see the logic of doing so.

Comment: Hey, I didn't get how to create a new dataset with the new data. I'm using a colab where all my data files (data_0.pt, data_1.pt,....data_1337.pt) are saved in a folder_path = '/content/data/processed' . Now how to assign all these files to the new dataset class?